# What should I do instead if I keep finding myself subscribing to something from within another subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rx-java, observable, system.reactive

I have a use case where I'm trying to gather info from a form (using Materialize in Angular2) and add it to firebase. Some information about the user already exists in said firebase, and I'd like the new entry in the database to contain a key pointing to an already-existing node ('users/:userId') elsewhere in the database.

In my case, specifically, I find myself having to get the current user from my authentication service, wait for that observable to publish userInfo so that I can query firebase for a user with that same email address, get the key of that user, and pass that key as part of the new object to the database.

Perhaps this code snippet will help clarify:

```
createMatchObj(result: any){
    let {matchUrlBound, athlete1NameBound, athlete2NameBound, tournamentNameBound, locationBound, tournamentDateBound, giStatusBound, genderBound, ageClassBound, rankBound, weightBound} = result;
    let matchDeets = new MatchDetails(tournamentNameBound, locationBound, new Date(tournamentDateBound), athlete1NameBound, athlete2NameBound, weightBound, rankBound, matchUrlBound, genderBound, giStatusBound === 'true', ageClassBound);
    let moves: Array<MoveInVideo> = new Array<MoveInVideo>();
    this.as.getCurrentUser()
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(userInfo => {
        console.log("got into getCurrentUser");
        this.db.getNodeIdFromEmail(userInfo.email).on("child_added", snapshot=>{
          let match = new Match(matchDeets, snapshot.key, moves);
          return Observable.of(match); //this clearly doesn't work
        });
      });
    //but a return statement here wouldn't wait for the subscriptions
  }
```

The createMatchObj method is called, along with a call to the database service, upon form submission:

```
  submitFormAndReturnToMain(){
    let values = this.getValues();
    let match = this.createMatchObj(values).subscribe(result=>{
      console.log(match);
      this.db.addMatchToDb(match);
      this.router.navigate(['landing']);
    });
  }
```

To illustrate:
[image: image of database structure]

I suspect that this question can be generalized very broadly, though, and it surprisingly doesn't seemed to have been asked this way on stack overflow before:

what's best practice for nested subscriptions like the above? I've been avoiding learning about switchMap() so far because I just barely understand observables in general. Is something like switchMap() the answer?

Happy to supply more information if that's needed:

Comment: Yes, `switchMap` is one way to do this.

Comment: The rxjs website has a questionnaire that helps you figure out which operator to use in a quite comfortable way

Comment: If you want to improve your understanding of observables, you can take a look at [this overview](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html) provided by RxJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very board term you can think of switchMap or mergeMap like promise .then. You would want to return an Observable instead of an subscription from `createMatchObj`. Problem here is to first use mergeMap/switchMap pass on `userInfo`, then you need to convert  `this.db.getNodeIdFromEmail(userInfo.email)` from a callback to an Observable

```js
createMatchObj(result: any){
    let {matchUrlBound, athlete1NameBound, athlete2NameBound, tournamentNameBound, locationBound, tournamentDateBound, giStatusBound, genderBound, ageClassBound, rankBound, weightBound} = result;
    let matchDeets = new MatchDetails(tournamentNameBound, locationBound, new Date(tournamentDateBound), athlete1NameBound, athlete2NameBound, weightBound, rankBound, matchUrlBound, genderBound, giStatusBound === 'true', ageClassBound);
    let moves: Array<MoveInVideo> = new Array<MoveInVideo>();
    return this.as.getCurrentUser().switchMap(userInfo => {
        console.log("got into getCurrentUser");
        return Rx.Observable.create(obs=>{
        this.db.getNodeIdFromEmail(userInfo.email).on("child_added", snapshot=>{
          let match = new Match(matchDeets, snapshot.key, moves);
          obs.next(match);
        });
        });
      });
    //but a return statement here wouldn't wait for the subscriptions
  }


    submitFormAndReturnToMain(){
    let values = this.getValues();
    let match = this.createMatchObj(values).takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(result=>{
      console.log(match);
      this.db.addMatchToDb(match);
      this.router.navigate(['landing']);
    });
  }
```

You can leave the `takeUntil` till last just before subscribing.

Comment: I've just now had the chance to try this. I get a,  "Property 'takeUntil' does not exist on type 'void' " error, and then a similar error about property 'subscribe' in the submitFormAndReturnToMain method. I suspect that it's because it thinks that the createMatchObj returns void, because the return statement is inside a switchMap call. Any recommendations for how I might fix this?

Comment: @Atticus29 i return an observable in createMatchObj , pls see the updated answer